# linux extract string from a file

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I would like to extract string after `x_rundir` from a file full with text.

Trying with

```bash
grep -w "x_rundir" xfile.txt
```

but it extracts whole sentence from the file

**xfile.txt:**

```
00:39:11-INFO: x_rundir: /i/am/a/path/
```

Expected result:

```
/i/am/a/path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this gnu-grep command:

```bash
grep -oP 'x_rundir: \K\S+' xfile.txt

/i/am/a/path/
```

Here:

- `-P` enabled Perl regex mode
- `-o` prints only matched text
- `\K` resets matched info
- `\S+` matches 1+ non-whitespaces

Comment: This works. Thanks. May I ask what are those \K \S+ thingy called? I would like to know more.

Comment: `\K` resets all matched information that comes before it. `\S+` matches 1 or more non-whitespace characters